# iPhone app which is only a local HTML file, how?

Tags: iphone, html, xcode, safari

I have a HTML Ajax website which consists only of one HTML file. How can I create an iPhone App out of it? The HTML file should be stored locally on the iPhone so it functions offline.

Answer (score 6):

```
UIWebView *htmlView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,380.0)];
[htmlView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
[self.view addSubview:htmlView];
[htmlView release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what level of AJAX you're using, the "CSS Ninja" has a [nice tutorial](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/how-to-create-offline-webapps-on-the-iphone) on how to add the proper code your HTML file to make it accessible offline.

Comment: Good hint! But I want to build a native iPhone App for the shop.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [iui](http://code.google.com/p/iui/).

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to do at least a tab bar with the webpage in one tab and an "about" or something in the other. Apple has been known to refuse apps that are just a straight up wrapper of a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found two very good video tutorials which are explaining how to build an "**UIWebView for iPhone App**"

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZcND6ZVOYw
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZKSbb40Jp8